# Particles disappear when render as object

Tags: particles, metaballs

Im trying to catch up with this tutorial, made with older version of Blender (working on 2.92):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tp8wStJ_6M
At 4:09 when adding the metaball and setting particles render from halo to render as objects, the particle completely disappear. Actually after setting object everything is gone.
Why is that? I'm puzzled.
Needless to say, some things don't work exactly the same way as in the tutorial, starting with particles size and many different aspects, so I rather played with that and tried to figure it out myself. Maybe something in partticle settings is wrong?

[image]

[image]

EDIT: These are my settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAjRt.png)
[image]
[image]

Comment: try setting the scale under "render as" set to 1

Comment: @Chris super simple, seemed to work ! thank you

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: I have the same problem, but my particle size is at .150, no matter how large I make them, they disappear. I can only see the animation when ther're set to render as Halo - even in previw, where I believed that shouldn't have an y influence.